# Remove the blank spaces

Tags: php

I have an external text file with a list of numbers like this:

```
35454
54545
45444
```

I want to output it like this:

```
'35454' 
'54545' 
'45444'
```

I would post my code, but Stack Overflow keeps giving me errors and cutting off my code when I try to post it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you mean that there's trailing spaces after the numbers?

You're looking for `trim()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean but this will do assuming that text.txt contains the values

```
$vals = file('text.txt');
foreach($vals as $v){
    echo '\''.trim($v).'\'<br />';

}
```

To remove blank spaces at the beginning and the end you can use `trim` or to remove all spaces something like `$num = str_replace(' ','',$num);` could work

Answer (score 0):

If those strings always are numbers, you you can cast them to `int` like

```
var_dump((int)'  42  ');
```

which will output

```
int(42)
```